# Whats the reason for Stack Exchange maintenance today (2020-02-15)

Tags: support, maintenance

There is no one rest of the world who can fill the vacuum of Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites. Stack Overflow got maintenance break now I got stack!!

Now anyone please tell me why the got maintenance break, or what's the update they did. 
[image]

Even though the site seems to load fine now, it would be nice to know what caused the outage earlier. There was nothing posted on Stack Status's blog or Twitter account at the time, and now there's only a simple "fixed it" message on the Twitter feed.

Comment: Note to potential future close voters: the outage happened on multiple SE sites (I saw it on Community Building) so it's not only applicable to one site, and this is asking about a *past* (not current) outage so it's not no longer reproducible.

Comment: They foo-ed the bar so it went fubar.

Comment: @sonic _"and this is asking about a past (not current) outage so it's not no longer reproducible"_ Well, how would that be a helpful question for future research, even when that outage was a confirmed event?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Having a post-mortem for an outage helps prevent such things from happening in the future and gives the public an insight into what happened and why.

Comment: @Sonicthe `Having a post-mortem for an outage helps prevent such things from happening in the future` But for whom? The ordinary users or the developers?

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for asking this, even though you will most likely be a little disappointed with the answer. At this point, we're not entirely sure what the cause of the outage was and we're still investigating it.

What we do know is that we hit a considerable number of timeouts across the network when attempting to connect to SQL Server. The exact error was:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Initially, we suspected a problem on the SQL side of things, but there is nothing in the SQL Server error log that confirmed an issue with SQL. We're still digging into logs to see if we can determine the cause and then push a fix for it.

Comment: [tag:status-temporary-burp-no-repro] then?

Comment: Is there not a failover duplicate server which can carry on seamlessly while the first one is being rebooted?

Comment: @user1306322 Yes we do have secondary servers that are used when we initiate a failover. This, however, was not a planned failover and we don't automatically failover our SQL Servers. Also this was not a reboot situation. All of the servers were online and running, but we had issues connecting. As I mentioned, we're still investigating the root cause of the outage.